# Can I Use coordinate [Lat,Long, Elevation, Time ]in GeoJSON File so that file can be used by any other Applications

Tags: json, parsing, geojson

Can I use coordinates [Lat,Long, Elevation, Time] in a GeoJSON file so that file can be used by any other application?

```
{ "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "LineString",
      "coordinates": [
        [102.0, 0.0,805,"22-08-2016 13:04:04"],
        [103.0, 1.0,806,"22-08-2016 13:05:04"],
        [104.0, 0.0,804,"22-08-2016 13:06:00"],
        [105.0, 1.0,808,"22-08-2016 13:07:40"]] 
      },
    "properties": {
      "prop0": "value0",
      "prop1": 0.0
      }
    }
  // "Using elevation and time in coordinate array elevation as numeric and time in string format
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be the [geoJSON specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946).

As they say in the section about [extending geoJSON](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-6) you can extend to add foreign members, but anything that alters the structure of the already defined types is referred to as [versioning geoJSON](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-8), and as such that kind of object should not be called a geoJSON.

You can check the specifications they define for a [position array](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.1.1).

TL;DR you can, but it wont be a geoJSON anymore and parsers are not guaranteed to work with it.